# Dissociate files from Nuget without removing from the project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a project with a few front-end frameworks obtained via and managed by Nuget (Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery UI ...).

I want to keep the files in my project, but remove them from Nuget's grip (I don't like the way Nuget organizes these files).

When I un-check the project for a library Nuget removes all the files it had installed, unless I've editted them (e.g. I over-wrote bootstrap.css with a customized version from getbootstrap.com).

As I do this from time-to-time, instead of backing up the `/Content` and `/Scripts` directories and adding back in the relevant files after removing the library from Nuget, I'd like to be able to dissociate *all* files of a particular library from Nuget at once without removing them from the project's directories. **Is that possible, by either the GUI or the console**?

I don't know if this issue is specific to a version(s) of Visual Studio, but mine is VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate for the part of "I don't like the way Nuget organizes these files"? If you remove NuGet from the picture, the good things that it does for you (detection of package updates, automatic package restore etc.) will be gone.

If you absolutely need to do this, one possible hack would be deleting packages.config from the project.

Comment: It's not all nuget packages I have issues with -- just the ones managing front-end libraries like Twitter Bootstrap. For example, I prefer having a single directory holding all the files (CSS, js, font-files) for a particular front-end library. For these, the "good things" Nuget does are (vastly) outweighed by the lack of control over where things go, which complicates, for example, how I manage custom CSS for Bootsrtap.  I'm fine with the way Nuget manages .net libraries, so I don't want to delete packages.config. Would it be a bad idea to edit packages.config by hand?